# Include image assets in a WordPress Gutenberg Block Plugin

Tags: wordpress, webpack, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a custom WordPress Gutenberg block and I want to use image assets (PNGs, JPGs) from my plugin folder, to be shown in both the Gutenberg editor and on the rendered page.

I am using Webpack to bundle my files for JS and SCSS. I tried adding the webpack image loader, which saves images into an 'assets' folder in my main plugin directory.

However, when I try to use my image assets from my Block's main JS file, I cannot find a way to access the full URL path of my images as running on my WordPress server, currently running in a docker container on localhost.

My hope was to find a WordPress method to return the path of my plugin directory, and use that to point to the image assets regardless of how they are bundled, but I have not been able to find a solution in the documentation.

It's possible to get the plugin directory using PHP using WordPress' built-in function:

```
function _get_plugin_directory() {
  return __DIR__;
}
```

This seems like it could help, however I do not know if it's possible to pass the returned plugin path into my JS file.

My plugin structure looks like this:

```
/assets // generated by Webpack
  - image.png
  - main.js
/blocks
  /block-example
    - image.png // <-- My image asset
    - index.js // <-- I want to use image.png here
  - index.js // loads in my block
blocks.php
```

The index.js file is where I want to show the image, using the standard WordPress `edit` and `save` functions:

```
import image from './image.png';

edit: props => {
  ...
  <img src={image} />
}
```

In the WordPress Gutenberg editor, images point to just the image file name (`./image.png` or `assets/image.png` etc), instead of the full path of the image where it sits inside the plugin directory (ie `localhost:8080/plugins/my-blocks/assets/image.png`) which results in the image not being found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm still looking into whether there's an official Gutenberg way to do this, but for now I've got this working in my plugin with [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

This works to pass data from PHP into enqueued Javascript so that data usually only accessible in PHP is accessible in Javascript as well.

So (likely inside `blocks.php` from your example), you would have something like:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-main-script',
    plugins_url( 'assets/main.js', __FILE__ ),
    array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components' ),
    '20190804',
    true
);
```

You can then enqueue any values you want to pass into your JS:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'my-main-script',
    'js_data',
    array(
        'my_image_url' => plugins_url( 'blocks/block-example/image.png', __FILE__ )
    )
);
```

This will ensure that the image path is accessible to javascript. Then from within your block itself, you can reference it:

```
<img src={js_data.my_image_url} />
```

You should now see your static image asset rendered within your block.

Answer (score 5):

Popping this in here for anyone that land here:

You can directly import images into react apps using webpack.

So assuming you're using some kind of webpack configuration (@wordpress/scripts, create-guten-block, or your own custom setup), you would simply import your image into the block file like so, assuming your image is in the same folder as the file you're importing into:

```
import image1 from "./image1.jpg"
```

And then use it like a URL wherever you need:

```
<img src={image1} alt="my image" />
```

Comment: Having tried this with a svg, I find that the svg code is imported into the block itself and not referred by path (check with code view in block editor).

Answer (score 0):

You can also acheive the same thing using the newer [wp_add_inline_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) function.

From the WordPress docs

> Though localization is the primary use, it (`wp_localize_script`) was often used to pass generic data from PHP to JavaScript, because it was originally the only official way to do that. wp_add_inline_script() was introduced in WordPress Version 4.5, and is now the best practice for that use case. `wp_localize_script()` should only be used when you actually want to localize strings.

Here's the code I used to pass an image url into a custom Gutenberg block using `wp_add_inline_script`. The below code was placed inside `blocks.php` as per the example.

In `wp_enqueue_script` code sample, `_get_plugin_url()` is my own custom function to retrieve the path for my plugin.

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-main-script',
    _get_plugin_url() . $block_path,
    [],
    filemtime( _get_plugin_directory() . $block_path )
);
```

I set up an array for the data I wished to pass in, eg

```
$js_data = array(
    'image_url' => _get_plugin_url() . '/assets/images/BACK.png',
);
```

Then used the `wp_add_inline_script` function

```
wp_add_inline_script(
    'my-main-script',
    'var jsData = ' . wp_json_encode( $js_data ),
    'before'
);
```

Inside the `/block-example/index.js` file which registers the block and defines its behaviour, I can access that variable like:

```
jsData.image_url
```